# Non-persistent data when app goes background

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, background, didreceivememorywarning

Is there a any chance that an in memory data might be lost when an iOS app goes to background?

for example if the OS give notice to the app with

`didReceiveMemoryWarning` and the app didn't take any action to release some space.

so far I have never notice this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not instantly, but the app may be terminated at any point, if other apps are used and the system decides, that it needs the memory blocked by your app.